# .NET windows app / google map api, cant search the same address twice

Tags: javascript, vb.net, visual-studio, google-maps, windows

a while back someone from stackoverflow helped me come with a nice solution to using google maps api on windows application

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com.mx/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=es"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder;
    var map;


    function initialize(address) {

        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': (address ? address : "Miami Beach, Flordia")}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Windows application code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("initialize", New String() {AddressM.Text})

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("http://datasharesas.com/CompanyAdmin/map2.html")
    End Sub
End Class
```

image of the project

[image]

now the issue is that when i look the same address once, it works perfectly.
when i search it twice i get a grey screen and when i search more than 3 times i get an error script

error message

[image]

how can this be fixed ?

thank you in advance,

Leo P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding is asynchronous, so in some cases, (depending on how fast it returns), your map is not yet created when you try to use it. You need to create the map first and geocode afterwrds. Try this instead:

```
    script type="text/javascript">
    // Global vars
    // Sorry, I can't be bothered typing "google.maps." every time. ;-)
       var G = google.maps;
       var map;
       var geocoder = new G.Geocoder();

        function initialize() {
          createMap();
          geocode('Chicago');
        }

        function createMap() {
            var myOptions = {
                center: new G.LatLng(0,0),
                zoom: 4,
                mapTypeId: G.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new G.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

function geocode(address){
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': (address ? address : "Miami Beach, Florida")}, function (results, status) {
                if (status == G.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new G.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });

        }


        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i tried the solution but when i load the html it starts with a script error :(  the error -> http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1815/googlemaperror2.png

Comment: That's a simple enough error to correct. Just add the missing }. Sorry, I only have one hand so I do make such errors when I type.

Comment: found the error, center: new G.LatLng(0,0); need to be center: new G.LatLng(0,0), Thank you

Comment: i got it to load the map of chicago but when i do a search for a different address it doesnt change, it stays in Chicago

Comment: Oh, gee..semicolon where there should be comma. Sorry about that. I'm glad you found it. I edited the answer in case it helps others :-)

Comment: That would be from the VB part. I guess that you need to change WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("initialize"....with WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("geocode" .... but I don't know VB at all.

Comment: that is cleared now :) worked nicely, on the html side how would you clear previous addresses searched? i did noticed if i searched two addresses close by, the previous marker would stay and not disappear in which case i dont need it and would create a little of confusion

Comment: I posted an answer about using only one marker to your other question.